# Can not connect to the databaseMongoParseError: Unescaped at-sign in authority section

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mean-stack

I am trying to connect to mongodb server in my nodeJS project. I have a db config file as DB.js

```
module.exports = {
    DB: 'mongodb+srv://user%40gmail.com:%24ugar@cluster-jfgsm.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true'
 };
```

username contains @ (%40) mark as it is an email id and the password contains $(%24) characters.

And i have connected that in my server.js file as

```
    mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    config = require('./config/DB');

    const app = express();

    mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
    mongoose.connect(config.DB,  { useNewUrlParser: true } ).then(
      () => {console.log('Database is connected') },
      err => { console.log('Can not connect to the database'+ err)}
    );
```

and I have added the custom `serve` option in my package.json file to run the nodemon.

```
"scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "serve": "nodemon server.js"
  },
```

But when i tried to run the project using the command `npm run serve`, i am getting an error message in the console

> Can not connect to the databaseMongoParseError: Unescaped at-sign in
>   authority section

I have searched many questions in the stack-overflow also but nothing worked for me.

Any help is appreciated. 
Thank You

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's okay to encode the password like so:

```
const DB_USER = 'user';
const PASSWORD = encodeURIComponent('hello@123'); 
const DB_URL = `mongodb://${DB_USER}:${PASSWORD}@ds331735.mlab.com:31772/any_db`;
```

If there's an `@` in your password, you should change it to `%40`.

Answer (score 2):

Found the same issue, but after all resulted that is not the mongodb atlas account user (which has email as the username) the one needed for login.

The user needed is one which has access to the cluster created in mongodb atlas.

`Project > clusters > [Select cluster]`

`Security tab > select/create new db user`

These users need not have special characters (there's even a message indicating that such chars will be encoded)

See image below:

[image: MongoDB cluster interface (as of Feb 2019)]

Answer (score 1):

```
const dbName = 'your db name';
const dbUser = 'your db username';
const dbPassword = 'your db user password';

const MONGODB_URI = `mongodb://${dbUser}:${dbPassword}@ds047207.mlab.com:47207/${dbName}`;
```

> Note : @ds047207.mlab.com:47207 its provide u in your account check.
>   its not connect try to simple username and password. create user ex:
>   username :asif , password :asif123
>   Bcoz i had create user with username :asif-vora and password :asif@1234 its getting error in database connection when i try with username :asif , password :asif123 its work fine :)

[image]

Comment: yeah... that is also my problem. I had some special characters in my username and password. and now i can not change the username. And still struggling to connect to mongodb

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to scape the @ and $ like

```
mongodb+srv://user\@gmail.com:\$ugar@cluster-jfgsm.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true
```

Comment: `{ useNewUrlParser: true }`  is needed as i am getting in console ` DeprecationWarning: current URL string parser is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new parser, pass option { useNewUrlParser: true } to MongoClient.connect.
`

Comment: I am doing the same as you can see in the question too.

Comment: what happened if you write the connection like this: `mongodb://user%40gmail.com:%24ugar@cluster-jfgsm.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true`

Comment: getting an error : MongoParseError: Unescaped at-sign in authority section

Comment: try to use this connection option: `{ uri_decode_auth: true }`

Comment: do you fix the problem?

Comment: not yet... still the same error is showing up. I have tried many options still the same

Comment: why not change username to another without @? is not good practice using @ to database username

Comment: email is used as an username by default while signing up in the mongodb server. and we can not change it after that. Thats the reason

Comment: Getting the same error. The temporary solution is just to delete that user and make a new user with some other simple username and password. I tried it.

Answer (score 0):

try this it is worked with me:

```
DB: mongodb://admin:<password>@nerdstore-shard-00-00-4iypj.mongodb.net:27017,nerdstore-shard-00-01-4iypj.mongodb.net:27017,nerdstore-shard-00-02-4iypj.mongodb.net:27017/nerdstore?ssl=true&replicaSet=nerdstore-shard-0&authSource=admin&retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

change it with ur shard.

Comment: you have 3 shard when create db, change it with yours db name shard and also username and password.

DB: mongodb://yourUsername:<yourpassword>@yourCluster-shard-00-00-4iypj.mongodb.net:27017,yourCluster-shard-00-01-4iypj.mongodb.net:27017,yourCluster-shard-00-02-4iypj.mongodb.net:27017/yourDatabase?ssl=true&replicaSet=yourCluster-shard-0&authSource=admin&retryWrites=true&w=majority

Answer (score 0):

If your username and password have any of these special characters

> / ? # [ ] @

you might encounter issues when connecting or running commands via the command line interface: / ? # [ ] @ Use the equivalent ASCII Encoding in your URI. for @ the equivalent is %40

Answer (score 0):

This issue came from in your mongoDB password. If gave password as string you will get this issue. So click autogenerate password when creating a user in mongoDB atlas.

Like the below image in atlas:

[image]

Answer (score -2):

very simple solution :
remove special char from your  password:

I also face issue. I had @ in password.

Solution : database access-> it will show your user, click on edit and update new password without special char.
then use this in your connection string.